# UIView setAnimationsEnabled completion block

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I'm writing a Unit Test for a ViewController and I'm using UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false) in my Test to disable Animations so that the following code gets executed immediately.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 3.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.neueUnterhaltungButton.alpha = 0.0
        self.neueUnterhaltungButton.isEnabled = false
        self.plusButton.isEnabled = false
        self.plusButton.alpha = 0.0
        self.okButtonTopConstraint.constant = self.okButtonTopConstraintConstant!
        self.tableViewTopConstraint.constant = self.tableViewTopConstraintExpandedConstant!
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { success in
        self.neueUnterhaltungSegmentedControl.selectIndex(0)
        self.teilnehmerSuchen("")
    })
```

This works only partially as expected. Everything inside of the animation block is executed, but the completion block isn't which is confusing to me. Is this a bug? Surely this can't be by design.

Answer (score 0):

Try to force an extra run-loop run before checking the expectations for the completion block content.

```
RunLoop.current.run(until: Date())
```

Apple doc: *If the duration of the animation is 0, this block is performed at the beginning of the next run loop cycle.*